# How can I ask moderator attention for a misspelled tag?

Tags: feature-request, support

...except for asking a question on meta, that is?

There's a new tag, called `oveprint`, lacking an 'r' somewhere between the e and p. Since I don't have wiki editing privs yet, how can I attend someone who has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking on meta's really the right way to do it. Although in this case, as there is only 1 instance of the tag, you can edit the question with the tag and correct the spelling yourself. If there's a bunch, then let us know.